# Prove that if $U$ is a linearly independent subspace of $V$ then the list formed by adding a vector $w\in V$ is linearly dependent iff $w\in$ span U

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am a high school student currently working through Axler's [*Linear Algebra Done Right*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Linear-Algebra-Right-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/3319110799/ref=asc_df_3319110799/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310867999190&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13725608295216391335&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006674&hvtargid=pla-435436051835&psc=1&th=1&psc=1) by myself and I have stumbled upon this question in the second exercise.

> Suppose that $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is linearly independent in $V$ and $w \in V$. Prove that if $(v_1 + w, ... , v_n + w)$ is linearly dependent then $w \in \text{span}(v_1,...,v_n)$.

**My proof is as follows:**

Let $(v_1,...,v_n)$ be linearly independent in $V$ and $w\in V$. Suppose $(v_1 + w,...,v_n + w)$ is linearly dependent in $V$, then there exist $b_j \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$b_1(v_1+w)+...+b_n(v_n+w)=0$$
Where not all $b_j=0$
$$\implies b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n+(b_1+...+b_n)w=0$$
$$\implies w=-\frac{b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n}{(b_1+...+b_n)}$$
$\because$ $w$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $(v_1,...,v_n)$ it lies in the span of $(v_1,...,v_n)$ $\therefore w \in \text{span}(v_1,...,v_n)$ $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

However I feel my method was lackluster and my writing ambiguous. What changes can I make to this proof so that it is to an acceptable degree of rigor?

Comment: What if $b_{1}+\ldots+b_{n} =0$ ?

Comment: I agree with @Lelouch that the case $b_1+\cdots+b_n=0$ is the biggest gap that needs to be closed. But also, notice that your proof never used the hypothesis that $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is linearly independent! and that is definitely a necessary hypothesis (consider $v_1=\cdots=v_n=0$ when $n\ge2$). Hopefully closing the identified gap will show you where the linear independence hypothesis is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\{v_{1} + w, v_{2} + w, \ldots, v_{n} + w\}$ is LD.

Consequently, if one considers the linear combination
\begin{align*}
\alpha_{1}(v_{1} + w) + \alpha_{2}(v_{2} + w) + \ldots + \alpha_{n}(v_{n} + w) = 0
\end{align*}

there exists at least one $\alpha_{k}\neq 0$. WLOG we shall assume that $k = 1$. Therefore we may claim that
\begin{align*}
(\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n})w = -\alpha_{1}v_{1} - \alpha_{2}v_{2} - \ldots - \alpha_{n}v_{n}
\end{align*}

Notice that $\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n} \neq 0$. If this were not the case, we could conclude that
\begin{align*}
\alpha_{1}v_{1} + \alpha_{2}v_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}v_{n} = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} = \ldots = \alpha_{n} = 0
\end{align*}

which contradicts the fact that $\alpha_{1}\neq 0$.

Based on such considerations, we are able to infer that $w\in\operatorname{span}\{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct but need some justification. You have to mention why $\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j \neq 0$ , otherwise the expression of $w$ is undefined.

Claim: $\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j \neq 0$

Suppose, $\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j = 0$

Then, $\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j w=0$

And, from $ \ b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n+(b_1+...+b_n)w=0$  implies $\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j v_j = 0$

And by linear independence we have $b_j=0$ for all $j$ , but you assume at least one $b_j\neq 0$